# Upper bound of min separation between n randomly chosen points in a figure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Given a rectangle of size $6\times12$, prove that if $7$ points in it are chosen uniformly at random, the distance between at least $2$ points is $\leq 5$.

I don't know how to approach this problem. The only thing I tried was choose the extreme points at corners, and at mid-points of the long sides and show that the last point will be $\leq 4.24$ units away from the nearest point, but this is in no way a proof, nor does it seem like the right way to approach problems of this type.

Also, how would you solve it for a general case, $n\times n$ being the square(or any figure?) and $m$ being the number of points chosen, wherein we need to prove that the distance between at least $2$ points $\leq f(n,m)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide your $6\times 12$ big rectangle into $3\times 4$ rectangles. There will be $6$ of these.

If you pick $7$ points, then since there are only $6$ small rectangles, there must be a small rectangle that contains at least $2$ of the chosen points (Pigeonhole Principle).

These $2$ points are distance  $\le \sqrt{3^2+4^2}$ apart.